# Generic Methods to consume WCF Services

Tags: vb.net, wcf, generics

I have a bunch of WCF services referenced in my Desktop Application.
All of these services have some common methods e.g. `GetAll()`, `GetAllAsync()`, `Add(record As Employee)`, `AddAsync(record As Employee)`.
Now, while creating a Inheritable form, is there a way I can make generic functions for these common service functionalities so that in inherited form I can only provide the service name as type.

Comment: Create an interface and implement them for the different services. When you create the form, supply the implementation either manually or through dependency injection container

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In fact, my services are in a huge number, and I want to avoid the implementation of each service.

Comment: I investigated the same question today by searching the internet for two hours. It seems it's not really possible. Jeff W. Barnes wrote in 2007   "WCF does not support the use of generic methods for service operation.  In other words, only concrete types can be used for service operations.  Open generic types cannot be used.  Now, it is important to clarify this is not a limitation of WCF.  Rather, it is a limitation of WSDL, which is used to expose service metadata to consumers.  There is no construct within WSDL to define a generic type".

Comment: @JRB Thank you very much for your comments. I have changed my approach after your comments.